# Geometric accuracy analysis of 2d rectangular models

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, computational-geometry, mean-square-error

> I have reconstructed set of rectangular objects lie on a 2D plane (for
>   ex. ABCD). All these objects are in a one coordinate system.  On the
>   other hand, I have reference models for all of them (for ex.
>   A’B’C’D’). But reference models are in another coordinate system.
>   *Here, I must say that although these two models are in two different coordinate systems, there scale is same but only different is their
>   origin.*
>
> Now, I want to analyze the geometric accuracy of my reconstruction. I
>   need to do some sort of RMSE analysis of vertices. But the problem is
>   as these two systems have two different origins; actually, I cannot
>   find an exactly corresponding point to overlap one another. Because my
>   original data set is point data. Therefore, I cannot find an exact
>   vertex even by manually. To solve this, I was thinking to shift one
>   system and overlap from a certain corner from the other model. But
>   then, I found the RMSE are not the same as when they would be in same
>   origin.

(I was created two artificial rectangles which are in a same coordinate system with same origin. And get the RMSE and then overlap one corner and then again get the RMSE of the rectangle. These two are not the same).

> So, I want your assistant to solve this.
>
> *I have uploaded a sample figure of my rectangles for your reference.*

[image]